# HttpWebRequest and WebResponse.GetResponse give incomplete response

Tags: c#, response, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm pretty RESTless right now because I keep getting incomplete responses from Amazon. I'm using the Product Advertising API, making one ItemLookup request to the server.

The C# code is pretty basic:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

string resultString;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The number of chars I recieve is 17408- pretty constant but I've seen something around 16k as well.

This is how it always ends:

```
...ount><CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode><FormattedPrice>EUR 11,33</FormattedPri
```

Is there something I don't know about HttpWebRequest or Amazon's API?

[the url](http://ecs.amazonaws.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=BLA&Condition=Used&IdType=ISBN&IncludeReviewsSummary=False&ItemId=3856814248&MerchantId=All&OfferPage=1&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=OfferListings,SalesRank,ItemAttributes&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2011-06-21T19:27:02Z&Version=2010-11-01&Signature=BLA) (don't care about the key) edit: bad idea, limit exceeded...

Comment: Are you able to duplicate the truncation of the information by viewing that URL in your web browser?

Comment: No. Works fine in all browsers.

Comment: Something to do with buffering in the stream/streamreader maybe? Try a flush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        s.Flush();
        resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Now I've got it. The problem was solved by flushing but in several places in my code. ;) Thanks to all.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I tried to Flush the stream, but doing so gives me a NotSupportedException. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: You may skip cast ```WebReponse``` to ```HttpWebResponse``` due to ```GetResponseStream``` is method of ```WebResponse``` class.